# For loop in R (Special Case: Wiener Process)

Tags: r, for-loop, montecarlo

I'm dealing right now with a valuation of Option prices for my university thesis.
We need to program some things in R. It's the first time I'm working with a programming software like R. I've been doing this for the last 2 weeks and this is where I went so far:

```
s <- 120
#Value of the stock today
sd <- 0.1
#standard deviation
d <- 0.003
#Drift

N <- 365
T <-1
dt <-T/N
t <- seq(0,T, length=N+1)
W <- c(0, cumsum(sqrt(dt)*rnorm(N)))
#plot( t, W, type="l", main="Wiener process", ylim=c(-1,1))

S <- s*exp(d+sd*W)
S
```

This is a simple generalized Wiener process which I want to turn into a Monte Carlo simulation.
For S there are now 366 (N+1) Values of the Stock path. What I need is a "for loop" which takes the last Value of S and allocates it into a vector (list vector), so that I can run the loop for example 10000 times, collect every last Value of S and get the average of the vector.

I have no idea how I can program such a for loop.
I would really appreciate if you could help me or give me some good hints.

Greetings from Germany
Christian

Comment: Step 1: Turn your code into a function, `my_wiener_process`. Only `return()` the last value of `S`. Step 2: `n = 10000; results = rep(NA, n); for (i in 1:n) results[i] <- my_wiener_process()`.

Comment: Thanks alot. The problem is, i don't even know how i can turn my code into a function

Comment: Put `my_wiener_process <- function () {` before all your code, and put `return(tail(S, 1)) }` at the end of all your code. See, e.g, most anything at  [how to write a function in R](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+write+a+function+in+R&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)

Comment: Wow it worked, thank you very much! You saved my day.

Comment: plus one for the giggles at my_wiener_process

Answer (score 0):

I never studied Wiener Processes, but I think this would be a simple outline of the code you're trying to achieve:

```
stock_prices <- s    #Initialise vector of stock prices
numIter <- 10^4      #Set number of iterations in the for loop

for(i in 1:numIter) {
  s <- stock_prices[i]  #This is the current stock price (for ith iteration / time step)

  #Calculate the next stock price here, call it next_price

  #Add price of next iteration / time step to your vector:
  stock_prices <- c(stock_prices, next_price)
}
```

`stock_prices` will be a vector of the 10,000 stock prices you simulated.

I don't know how you calculate the next stock price from S, but if you draw from the values of S randomly, then it might be useful to check out the function `sample` (type `?sample` for help on it).

Hope that helps

Comment: "Growing" the vector inside the loop like that is very bad practice - needless inefficiency. See [Circle 2 of the R Inferno](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf).

Comment: I agree that it's not the most efficient, but it's easy to grasp. Since when I started writing this, he'd just said he didn't know how to write a function, I thought basic / easy code was more important than efficiency. I'm glad your comments sorted him out.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to run code repeatedly, putting it in a function is nice (but not absolutely necessary). I will refer to all the code in your question as `<your code>`.

To  make a function that runs your code,

```
my_function = function() {
    <your code>
}
```

The function will, by default, return its last line, in this case `S`. You only want the last element of `S`, `tail(S, 1)`. So we can modify the function to return only that:

```
my_function = function() {
    <your code>
    return(tail(S, 1))
}
```

We can then call it in a `for` loop `n` times and assign the result. It is best to pre-allocate the vector for the results so that an appropriately sized block of memory can be set aside for it up front:

```
n = 10000
results = rep(NA, n)
for (i in 1:n) {
    results[i] <- my_function()
}
```

This is equivalent to

```
n = 10000
results = rep(NA, n)
for (i in 1:n) {
    <your code>
    results[i] <- tail(S, 1)
}
```

And, for that matter, it is also equivalent to

```
results = replicate(n, my_function())
```

which is a handy shortcut.

If you want to be fancy, you could parameterize your function:

```
my_nice_function = function(s = 120, sd = 0.1, d = 0.003, N = 365) {
    T <- 1
    dt <- T / N
    t <- seq(0, T, length = N + 1)
    W <- c(0, cumsum(sqrt(dt) * rnorm(N)))
    S <- s * exp(d + sd * W)
    return(tail(S, 1))
}
```

Now `my_nice_function` has default values as in your code, but you can easily adjust them, e.g., to run the 50 simulations with `sd = 0.2` you can do this:

```
replicate(50, my_nice_function(sd = 0.2))
```